# Hibernate named paremeter: set view as parameter

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm wondering if its possible to pass a view or materialized view as a parameter in Hibernate.  For example:

```
String view = "some_view";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("refresh materialized view :view;");
query.setParameter("view", view);
query.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the name of the view as parameter. Instead you can construct the string say 'REFERSH_QUERY' and pass it to createNativeQuery method. So, your code should look like:

`String REFERSH_QUERY = "refresh materialized view " + viewName;
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(REFERSH_QUERY);
query.executeUpdate();`

You could pass the viewName as parameter to this function. Or you could also write a separate function to construct the Query. Hope it helps!